# Move object item up or down but keep same key and value

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
var fields =  {
    g8fdfc8: {
        label: 'Email',
        logic: []
    },

    ac1200: {
        label: 'Age',
        logic: []
    }
}
```

I want to move for example key and value up "ac1200", so the result should be like this:

```
var fields =  {
    ac1200: {
        label: 'Age',
        logic: []
    }

    g8fdfc8: {
        label: 'Email',
        logic: []
    },
}
```

Wonder if this can be accomplished.
I can't find a solution even with ChatGPT.

EDIT: Basicly i am building a VUE form editor but the app was written in jquery, that json format is like that.
So i have 2 buttons, one to move a item(field) up inside the fields object.
one to move down.

Comment: objects won't follow an order for its elements

Comment: Do you need to sort inline or recreate is fine?

Comment: sorted by what? property names (ac1200) or what?

Comment: in general you would sort the data after retrieving it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fields =  {
    g8fdfc8: {
        label: 'Email',
        logic: []
    },

    ac1200: {
        label: 'Age',
        logic: []
    }
}
var val = fields['g8fdfc8'];
delete fields['g8fdfc8'];
fields.g8fdfc8 = val;
console.log(JSON.stringify(fields));
```

Comment: Good idea but the fields are dynamic and will move up or down

Answer (score 0):

Your fields would have to be an array. The order of object keys cannot be sorted.

Now, you can use the `splice` method to move the `ac1200` item up by by 1.

```js
var fields = [
  { key: 'foobar'  , value: { label: 'Name'  , logic: [] } },
  { key: 'g8fdfc8' , value: { label: 'Email' , logic: [] } },
  { key: 'ac1200'  , value: { label: 'Age'   , logic: [] } }
];

const moveUp = (data, key) => {
  const index = data.findIndex(item => item.key === key);
  if (index > 0) {
    data.splice(index - 1, 0, data.splice(index, 1)[0]);
  }
}

const moveDown = (data, key) => {
  const index = data.findIndex(item => item.key === key);
  if (index !== -1 && index < data.length) {
    data.splice(index + 1, 0, data.splice(index, 1)[0]);
  }
}

moveDown(fields, 'foobar'); // Move down by 1
moveUp(fields, 'ac1200');   // Move up by 1

console.log(fields);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Object keys definitely do have a deterministic order.

Comment: @Unmitigated I just said that you could not sort the keys yourself.

Comment: Working to transfer code from jQuery to Vue. 
And if the order of object keys cannot be sorted this might be the way.

Answer (score 0):

**Avoid using object as hash arrays, use usual arrays with `id` fields. Objects are more difficult to handle than arrays (arrays have a bunch of methods for manipulating/transforming).**

Anyway, a generic approach would be

1. Get keys of an object into an array
2. Rearrange keys as you like
3. Reduce to an object back

Here we sort the keys alphabetically:

```js
var fields =  {
    g8fdfc8: {
        label: 'Email',
        logic: []
    },

    ac1200: {
        label: 'Age',
        logic: []
    }
}

fields = Object.keys(fields).sort().reduce((obj, key) => (obj[key] = fields[key], obj), {});

console.log(fields);
```

If you want to change an object in-place delete fields first so they would be added to the end in sorted order:

```js
var fields =  {
    g8fdfc8: {
        label: 'Email',
        logic: []
    },

    ac1200: {
        label: 'Age',
        logic: []
    }
}

Object.keys(fields).sort().forEach((key, val) => (val = fields[key], delete fields[key], fields[key] = val));

console.log(fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fields = {
  foo: { label: 'foo' },
  bar: { label: 'bar' },
  baz: { label: 'baz' },
  bat: { label: 'baz' },
}

function compare(v1, v2, k1, k2) {
  if (v1.label < v2.label) return -1;
  if (v1.label > v2.label) return 1;
  if (k1 < k2) return -1;
  if (k1 > k2) return 1;
  return 0
}

function sortObject(o, comp) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(o)
      .sort(([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) => comp(v1, v2, k1, k2))
  )
}
const result = sortObject(fields, compare)

console.log(result)
// const result = {
//   bar: { label: 'bar' }, // bar < baz (label)
//   bat: { label: 'baz' }, // bat < baz (key)
//   baz: { label: 'baz' },
//   foo: { label: 'foo' },
// }
```